# Where can I find a good asp.net 4.0 FAQ system?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I've googled for ages, and not being a programmer, I'm looking for a FAQ system / asp.net 4.0.  I can't find anything that can help me build a FAQ system that's NOT database-driven.  For instance, [FAQ Lite](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/faq-lite/)  is perfect, but it's not written in asp.net.

Can anybody help me out on how to **build** a FAQ system that's not database driven?  Thanks!

Comment: This will likely be closed as off-topic because it's not a programming question, it's product advice.  Also, the reason you're not finding a lot is that most good FAQs ***are*** database-driven because it's a lot easier to maintain a database than another storage medium.  Is there a reason a database-driven FAQ won't work?

Comment: Now if you were asking for specific advice on how to BUILD such a system, and had included what you've already tried, rather than asking for a pre-built solution, THEN it would be on-topic.

Comment: My web host makes me  pay for every DB; you have to purchase 'em.  But I've seen tons of questions just like mine that don't get closed.  "Where can I get this", "Where can I get that", etc. .... in fact, most get upgraded.  But at this point, I don't mind; I'm just trying to see if anyone can help.

Comment: @Jason-Do you need a helpdesk type or a simple faq system?

Comment: OK.  Good luck.  I'm not aware of any, but in all honesty, building one using an XML file wouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Just a simple faq system where I can have 20 or so questions and answers to the most commonly asked questions, coder.

Comment: Then it's just simple to use make use of jquery and you can have a look at here http://tutorialzine.com/2010/08/dynamic-faq-jquery-yql-google-docs/ if you are willing to work with JQuery

Comment: Yes, I do work with jquery.  Thanks coder!  That's exactly what I needed!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need,based on what you mentioned it's easy to do in Jquery as shown in the following article.

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/08/dynamic-faq-jquery-yql-google-docs/

Comment: I'm glad someone was able to help him!  +1.

Comment: @David-Thank you so much.Actually I am also using the same in one of my websites.So I could help him. :)